# Bootstrap Deployment - Not rendering on server

Tags: deployment, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just deployed my first ASP.NET MVC app, which uses Bootstrap.

Everything works fine on my development machine, but Bootstrap does not appear to be working at all on the server.

Is there a Bootstrap deployment guide anywhere? Anything in particular that I should look at?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the css and js file are linked correctly and files are available on server.

Comment: Noushad, thank you for the reply. The problem turned out to be an issue with Telerik/Kendo that was preventing the load of other js and css files. After upgrading to a new version, the problem was resolved.